# Unexpected results - Google Autocomplete against yorkshire

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete

I am getting unexpected results against 'Yorkshire' using Google Maps auto-complete API. I have filtered the results to only display regions of UK. Please help me

Following are the results I am getting while search for Yorkshire:

- Yorkshire du Nord, Royaume-Uni
- Yorkshire Oriental, Reino Unido
- Yorkshire del Sur, Reino Unido

Below is the code:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=MYGooGleAPiKey" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&language=en"></script><script>
$(function() {

    var options = {
        types: ['(regions)'],
        componentRestrictions: {country: 'uk'},
        region: ['(GB)']
    };

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#txt_search")[0], options);

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        //console.log(place.address_components);
    });
});</script>
```

Comment: Does API offer language restriction as well?

Comment: it seems like a language problem..

Comment: Hi @Konstantin Pribluda

I have tried with 
    language: ['(en)']

but still have no impact on it :(

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use `'GB'` instead of `'(GB)'`? The documentation doesn't mention brackets but does mention a 2-letter code.

Comment: Hi @AndrewLeach thanks for your time, this change is also not making any difference in the results...

Comment: types: ['geocode'] worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug in the API, see https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8619 and star if you want to see them fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In the  ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2 compatible country code specification country 'uk' doesn't exists.
Have you tried it with GB?

Check this link: http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/country_codes/country_names_and_code_elements.htm