# Google Places Autocomplete returning non-English results

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Google Places Autocomplete API to return location matches on a drop down search box.

We noticed recently that whilst searching for 'Yorkshire', the API is returning non-English results:

- Yorkshire du Nord
- Yorkshire De L'Ouest
- Yorkshire Del Sur

A quick search reveals this Stack thread, which strangely also concerns Yorkshire - [Unexpected results - Google Autocomplete against yorkshire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828345/unexpected-results-google-autocomplete-against-yorkshire)

However, I have tried everything in that thread, and the API is still returning these results. I am pretty sure language is not the problem in this case, as despite the region name being in French/Spanish, 'United Kingdom' is still returned in English. Our original API call did not specify any language=, but adding it with en or en-GB doesn't seem to make any difference.

Our current query is [here](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=yorkshire&language=en&sensor=false&types=(regions)&components=country:uk&key=xxx).

It almost seems as if the result being returned is just plain incorrect, but I find that hard to believe. Any ideas?

Comment: @jimpanzer Why change the full linked API request to a 'here' link? I kept it expanded so people can see what arguments I'm passing to the API.